# While loop printing out something if constraints aren't met

Tags: python

I want my program to have a constraint on the number of tests it is able to take in. While the input is out of range the program should restart and also print out that the number wasnt in the range.

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
import math
arr = []
tn = 1

t = int(input("How many test cases do you have? ").strip())

while t < 1 and t > 10^5:
    print("go again, the number is not in the range")

for i in range(t):
    n = int(input("What number do you want to test? ").strip())
    arr.append(n)
    
for x in range (0, len(arr)):
    b5 = arr[x]/5
    b3 = arr[x]/3
    print("Test for divisability by 3 No." + str(tn) + " " + str(math.floor(b3)))
    print("Test for divisability by 5 No." + str(tn) + " " + str(math.floor(b5)))
    tn = tn + 1
```

I tried to make this `while` loop, but it doesn't seem to print out anything.

```
while t < 1 and t > 10^5:
    print("go again, the number is not in the range")
```

Comment: `10^5` happens to be 15 - that's the bitwise exclusive OR operator, not exponentiation.  Use `10**5` or `1e5`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a logic error in your code. How can `t` be both less than `1` and greater than `10^5` at the same time?

But you also need to prompt for `t` in the loop or it will not end.

You likely meant:

```
while t < 1 or t > 10^5:
    print("go again, the number is not in the range")
    t = int(input("How many test cases do you have? ").strip())
```